# Casting Generic

Tags: java, generics, casting

Is it possible to cast a generic object to something like a string?

I thought casting generics would be similar to normal object casting like:

```
public String tempString;
public E genericObject;

tempString = ((String) genericObject);
```

however, when compiling I still get a incompatible type error.

```
required: String 
found:    E
```

Comment: you sure the error is on that line?  are there any bounds on E?

Comment: Show us some more code. The class declaration?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this error. The cast worked fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do what you want, but you need to go via another cast first:

```
public String tempString;
public E genericObject;

tempString = (String) ((Object) genericObject);
```

The issue is that you can't cast "sideways" in a hierarchy, you can only cast down. That is, you can cast from `Object` to `String`, but not from `Number` to `String`.

Note, that if `E` really isn't a string, you will get a [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html), however if you are only doing this in circumstances that you *know* that `E` is really a string, then you will be fine.

Comment: This is possible but don't expect the generic object to be a usable string. It will be a string with more or less random values and potentially cause an exception.

Comment: @TwoThe Actually, the result will either be a String, or a ``ClassCastException``. I have added a comment to clarify that.

Answer (score -1):

You can. However only if E and String are compatible.

During runtime the JIT "replaces" the type E with the actual type you have chosen during class creation. If you for example created the generic class with Integer as E, your code becomes:

```
public String tempString;
public Integer genericObject;

tempString = ((String) genericObject);
```

That is why it won't work.

If you want to make sure the generic is castable to a specific class, you can limit the possible generic types in the form `generic<E extends String>` (there is however no class in Java that extends String).

Comment: 1. Erasure happens during **compile** time. 2. `<E extends String>` includes `String`.